Weibull analysis with confidence interval in spss
I’m trying to do the Weibull analysis and to show the confidence interval in spss. I have the following variables:

Shear bond strength, which shows the maximal strength till the material breaks
Adhesive type
Weibull gradient line should be done for each adhesive type specifically.

I have tried with following analysis:

Parametric accelerated failure time
Life tables
Kaplan-Meier
As soon as I put the strength variable in the time field or in any field everything grays out and I can’t perform the analysis.
I don’t have missing data.
I also tried with status= 1 but still doesn’t function.
How can I solve this problem?

